# Installing Ubuntu 13.10 on Lenovo G510

Tags: installation, 13.10

I just bought a new lenovo G510 laptop with FREE DOS.Specs of my laptop are

4th gen core i5 4200M processor
4GB RAM
500 GB HardDisk

I downloaded, amd64 bit iso file from the website, made my pendrive bootable using unetbootin on windows, when I connected bootable pendrive to my new machine, firstly it showed me a window which had two options, 1)Try ubuntu 2) Install Ubuntu..

When I clicked on Install Ubuntu then screen got blank and installation process didnt start..

So I am not understanding what wrong I am doing here..

Please help me out

Regards
Ranjit

Comment: I tried going through through the link but still its not working

Comment: If it still doesn't work please file a bug (one of the answers in that question shows you how to do it)

Comment: Issue solved. I solved it by changing the boot mode to legacyFirst. I think ubuntu should do it by default

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, for some reason the brightness of the screen was turned low. Click on the function key to increase the brightness (it should be in the top row on your keyboard with a sun and a plus icon). Once you increase the brightness it should work fine.